# How do i express this sql statement in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I tried poking around but only see some basic examples.

I am looking to express the following:

`select average((a+b)/c) from my table`

I have:

```
db.props.aggregate( [    { $group: { _id: "$id", a_: { $avg: "$a"
},b_:{$avg:"$b"} } },    {$match:{a_:{$gt:0},b_:{$gt:0}}} ] )
```

but i am definitely missing some pieces. i tried applying the operations in the `$avg` statement but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
{ 
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id", 
    average: {
        $avg: {
            $divide: [
                {$add: ["$a","$b"]},
                "$c"
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```